# Which one is the property that has the committer and the message in Buildbot?

Tags: buildbot

I have found a way to print out on a file on the master, every time that I get a commit on my project:

```
f.addStep(StringDownload(Interpolate("%(prop:got_revision)s\n"), slavedest="/Users/master/data/commit.txt"))
```

Now, I would like to have also the user that made the commit, and the message (if any), but the manual for Buildbot seems to omit the name for some of the properties (found got_revision by chance, like most of the Buildbot answers).

What (prop:) should I pass to obtain also the name of the committer and the message? I want to save on a text file on the server, the equivalent of

```
git log -1
```

But I was able to find only the commit.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In theory you can access changes properties this way:

```
 changes = self.getProperty("changes") or [] # returns None if there are no changes
 for ch in changes:
     changed_by = ch.who
```

But I haven't tried it myself

Comment: Yeah, that is in the class, but if you try to pass it to the stringDownload step, it will complain.